# Create ODBC Connection from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, windows-server-2008

I need help connecting from a blank access 2010 database to my remote SQL Server 2005 database. This is because I'm going to write all my client apps in Access, and store everything on the server with SQL Server. I'm using the wizard, and trying to make a new DSN. What do I put for:

```
Which SQL Server do you want to connect to?
Server:
```

The server is windows server 2008, and it is remote. I've been connecting to it with a .RDP file, but I'm not sure how to set up the link.

Please ask me to clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the IP address or the Windows Host Name for the server that has SQL Server on it.

You'll need to make sure that your server has port 1433 open in it's internal software firewall. If you're going through any kind of router that router will also need to have port forwarding and possibly the firewall opened up for port 1433.

Also, you'll need to make sure that your SQL Server instance is setup to listen on TCP/IP with port 1433 (unless you choose a different port).

You might be best off trying to connect to it from SQL Server Management Studio first. Once you have that working you should have an easier time setting up your DSN.

For troubleshooting, see this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/22/sql-server-2005-connectivity-issue-troubleshoot-part-i.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/09/30/sql-server-2005-remote-connectivity-issue-troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: Here's my problem, I've only been accessing the server via remote desktop access(.RDP file). I've been connecting to mail.blahblah.com where blahblah is the domain name. Here's what I've tried so far:

mail.blahblah.com
mail.blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS
mail.blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS,1433
blahblah.com
blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS
blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS,1433
TERM.blahblah.com
TERM.blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS
TERM.blahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS,1433

Where TERM is the name of the computer(I think). I just can't seem to figure this out even though it seems so simple.

Thank you so much :)